# Exercise 1: Galois Theory (J. Rotman)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

*Definition:* Let $F$ a figure in the plane, its symmetry group is defined by $\Sigma(F):=\{\sigma \in O(2,\Bbb R)\mid \sigma(F)=F\}$. Here $O(2,\Bbb R)$ denotes the real orthogonal group.

**Exercise 1:**

$\quad$ *a)* If $F$ is a square, prove that $\Sigma(F)\cong D_8$, the [dihedral group](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralGroup.html) of order $8$.

$\quad$  *b)* If $F$ is a rectangle that is not a square, prove that $\Sigma(F)\cong\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$.

$\quad $ *c)* Give an example of quadrilaterals $Q$ and $Q'$ with $\Sigma(Q)\cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $\Sigma(Q')=1$.

**Context:** As said in the title, this exercise comes at the end of a chapter in a book. I summarized this chapter [in this sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11745/41).

**My thoughts:**

$\quad$ *a)* It is clear to me that there is $4$ symmetry axis in a square. The induced symmetry $\sigma$ are linear, and preserve distances. This makes $8$ elements, since $\sigma$ is of order $2$. Moreover, we know from Theorem 3 (in the summary) that $\Sigma(F)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_4$ and $D_8$ [has eight elements](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_dihedral_group:D8#Elements). But I can't really conclude from here (and the beginning proof doesn't sound very rigorous).

$\quad$ *b)* Here, we have $2$ symmetry axis each symmetry is of order $2$ and we can compose them so it makes sens to me that $\Sigma(F)\cong\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$. However, I am struggling (again) to write that down in a more mathematical way.

$\quad$ *c)*

$\quad$ [image]

**PS:** diversity of approaches is very welcome

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by your answer to part a. There are four symmetry axes all right. That gives you four reflections and the identity mapping. A total of five symmetries so far (all those groups of order two share the identity mapping as an element, so you should not overcount). Some are missing! Hint: what is the composition of two different reflections?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ah right... I forgot that these symmetries are their own inverse (that is why I counted them twice). "what is the composition of two different reflections?" a rotation?

Comment: Correct. You forgot about rotations.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok but now, I should prove that these are the only elements of $\Sigma(F)$ (isn't it?).

Comment: Correct again. Consider the following. Pick one corner of the square. Call it $P$. $\sigma$ needs to map $P$ to another corner, right? That's four choices. Given that you know $\sigma(P)$ how many choices for $\sigma(Q)$, when $Q$ is one of the corners neighboring $P$? Note that the distance between $\sigma(P)$ and $\sigma(Q)$ must be equal to the distance between $P$ and $Q$. Does knowing $\sigma(P)$ and $\sigma(Q)$ uniquely determine $\sigma$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, "Call it P. σ needs to map P to another corner, right?" yes, this is Lemma 2 (in the summary). So, for a vertex $P$ we have $4$ choice. If $Q$ is a neighbor vertex, we have $2$ choices. Finally the other vertices $R,S$ are imposed because they have to be mapped on the opposite corners of $P$ and $Q$ respectively. So there are $4\cdot 2=8$ elements in $\Sigma(F)$. Since it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$ and $D_8$ is the only subgroup of $S_4$ with 8 elements, we have $D_8 \cong \Sigma(F)$.

Comment: Ok, now for the rectangle: let $P$ be a vertex of $F$, then we have $4$ choices for $\sigma(P)$ and this fixes completely $\sigma$ (since the distance to the neighbors of $P$ has to be preserved). It follows that $\Sigma(F)$ has $4$ elements. $\Sigma(F)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$. However it seems that there more than one subgroup with $4$ elements in $S_4$. How can I manage to ensure that it is $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: First you show that there are four elements, an that that the elements can commute. Then the group is either isomorphic at $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. And then, remark that all element are of order 2, and thus, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2):

**a)** May be we can describe them.

Let denote $$\sigma :P\mapsto Pe^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\quad\text{and}\quad\rho:P\mapsto -P$$ You clearly have the identity, $\sigma$, $\sigma ^2$ and $\sigma ^3$ and $\rho$ that are in $\Sigma(F)$. Now if you apply $\rho$, then you can also apply $\sigma, \sigma ^2$ and $\sigma ^3$ on $\rho(P)$, therefore $\sigma \rho,\sigma^2\rho$ and $\sigma ^3\rho$ are also in $\Sigma(F)$, we thus have $8$ elements. Now remark that $$\sigma ^4=1,\quad \rho^2=1,\quad\text{and}\quad\sigma \rho\sigma \rho=1,$$ therefore, $\Sigma(F)\cong \mathcal D_8$.

**b)** Here, you only have the identity, $\varphi:=\sigma ^2$, $\rho$ and $\varphi\rho$. It's easy to prove that all these element has order 2 and that they commute. You know that a commutative group with 4 elements is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$ or $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. But as all these elements has order $2$, we conclude that $\Sigma(F)\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$.

**c)** Your figure are correct.

Comment: This is nicely geometric approach. How can you be sure that there are no more elements in $\Sigma(F)$?

Comment: You can permute $4$ element of at most $24$ way. Therefore th number of element of $\Sigma(F)$ has to divide $24$. For $a)$ you see for example that $(1\ 2)\notin \Sigma(F)$ (because $(1\ 2)\notin O(2,\mathbb R)$, therefore, the order of $\Sigma(F)$ is at most 8. But we found $8$ automorphisms, therefore there is $8$ element in $\Sigma(F)$. For $b)$, of course that there is at most $8$ elements (because a square is a rectangle), but for exemple $\sigma$ is not in $\Sigma(F)$ therefore there is at most $4$ elements. But we found $4$ automorphism, therefore $\Sigma(F)$ has $4$ elements. Got it ?

Answer (score 1):

Part (a): let $r$  be the rotation of $\frac \pi2$ around the centre of the square and $s$ the symmetry with respect to one of the diagonals of the square. The other (axial) symmetries are $sr, sr^2, sr^3$. Symmetry with respect to the centre of the square is $r^2$ and the inverse rotation is $r^3$.

Now the dihedral group $D_4$ is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the following relations: $$a^4=1,\quad b^2=1,\quad ab=ba^3.$$
These are exactly the relations satisfied by $r$ and $s$. So you just have to define a morphism from $\Sigma(\text{square})$ to $D8$ (or $D_4$ according to other standards) by sending $r$ to $a$, $s$ to $b$, extending to the other elements so that it is compatible with the group laws.

Part (b): same method. $\Sigma(\text{rectangle})$ contains four elements: $\operatorname{id}$, the symmetry  with respect to the centre of the rectangle $s_O$ and the symmetries with respect to the horizontal and vertical axes, $s_H$  and $s_V$. Define a map from $\Sigma(\text{rectangle})$ to $\mathbf Z_2\times \mathbf Z_2$ by sending $\operatorname{id}$ to $(0,0)$, $s_H$ to $(1,0)$, $s_V$ to $(0,1)$ and $s_0$ to $(1,1)$, then check it is compatible with the group laws

Comment: I really like the idea of building explicitly the isomorphism. But, as for @idm, how can you be sure that the elements of $\Sigma(F)$ are exactly the ones you describe?

Comment: Plane isometries are generated by (axial) symmetries. There are $4$ only symmetries which  preserve a square (the image of a point characterises a symmetry), and we have them all. Hence we have the whole symmetry group.